# I have issue related Dropdown Menu Flutter Windows Application

Tags: flutter

I have facing an issue that when I press tab on dropdown menu it is selecting menu entries in background without opening dropdown menu how can I stop it?

I have tried to change source code but I can't understand it. I have tries to change it manually but it won't work if anyone knows how can I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a same problem please using this code.

```
RawKeyboardListener(

  focusNode: FocusNode(),

  onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {

    if (event is RawKeyDownEvent) {

      // Check for the Tab key and prevent default behavior

      if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.tab) {

        event.logicalKeyHandled = true;
      }
    }
  },

  child: YourDropdownWidget(),

)
```